# Xamarin Forms WebView.CanGoBack always returns false on UWP

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms

Using the Xamarin Forms WebView control, I'm overriding the OnBackButtonPressed() and finding that the CanGoBack always returns false in UWP.

I don't see this problem in Android.

Is this a XF bug or am I doing something wrong?

Note: I'm running XF v2.3.3.193

EDIT: I upgraded to XF 2.3.4.247 and the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a code sample and reproduce your issue when the WebView browse several website. And I have found reason in the [Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT/WebViewRenderer.cs) source code.

```
void UpdateCanGoBackForward()
{
 ((IWebViewController)Element).CanGoBack = Control.CanGoBack;
 ((IWebViewController)Element).CanGoForward = Control.CanGoForward;
}
```

The `CanGoBack` property will be changed when `UpdateCanGoBackForward` method invoked. And `UpdateCanGoBackForward` method was called only when the native  `NavigationCompleted` event was invoked. So if some website could not be loaded quickly, the `CanGoBack` property would not be changed.

You can improve this design by custom WebView. And you could follow the code below.

**CustomWebView.cs**

Add the new property for `CustomWebView`.

```
public class CustomWebView : WebView
{
    public bool CCanGoBack { get; set; }

    public CustomWebView()
    {

    }
}
```

**CustomWebViewRenderer.cs**

And change the property when the ContentLoading  event invoked.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]

namespace CustomWebViewTest.UWP
{
    public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.ContentLoading += Control_ContentLoading;
            }
        }

        private void Control_ContentLoading(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebViewContentLoadingEventArgs args)
        {
            (Element as CustomWebView).CCanGoBack = Control.CanGoBack;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPage.cs**

```
private void backClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (Browser.CCanGoBack)
     {
         Browser.GoBack();
     }       
 }
```

Comment: Just a comment that although this did fix UWP, it broke Android (since I did not have a custom renderer for droid).  I wasn't sure what to do in the Android renderer so rather than create one, I just do a RuntimePlatform check and check either CCanGoBack or CanGoBack depending on the platform.